# TortoiseSVN: Show status of multiple working folders in parent folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository, working-copy

I have repository configured like this:

```
\Util_1
  \branches
  \tags
  \trunk
\Util_2
  \branches
  \tags
  \trunk
...
```

Now, on my local disk i have:

```
\dev   
  \Utils
    \Util_1
    \Util_2
```

In Util_xx folders are only trunks. If I enter the Utils folder, TortoiseSvn shows status icons for each Util. Unfortunately, Utils folder that contain them doesn't have any status icon. It's not really a checkout folder so i can't see that there is something changed in it unless I enter it. Looking at it from Dev folder shows nothing about it. So it happened that I didn't checkin immediately and since I'm not regular developer for this repo, I forgot a file there for month.

Is there any way to make TortoiseSVN show cumulative status of child folders in parent folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ***could*** install an svn server locally, set up a 'Utils' repo that you keep up to date with 'externals' links to each of the Util_1, Util_2, etc., ... and even then I don't know for sure if it would work because I don't know if TortoiseSVN shows the status of external children in the icon of the parent.

You ***should*** just change your folder hierarchy to align with your actual repository hierarchy.  Like this:

```
\dev
  \Util_1
  \Util_2
  \Non-Util_Project_Repo
```

You should also change your process.  If there is a project that you don't work on for a month at a time or longer, why are you keeping a working copy of it anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Because `Utils` isn't a checkouted folder and doesn't contain `.svn`, you can't do anything with it using SVN.

Answer (score 0):

No.  For exactly the reason you gave ... TortoiseSVN knows nothing about `Utils` or `dev` since neither are working copies.

Answer (score 0):

No. However, if Utils_1 and Utils_2 have a parent directory in your repository (see below), you could do a checkout of the entire Utils directory which would show the accumalated status.  I would not advise this though, because checking out all branches and tags could get messy.

```
\Utils
  \Util_1
    \branches
    \tags
    \trunk
  \Util_2
    \branches
    \tags
    \trunk
...
```